# FQL equivalent to Graph API pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-fql

I know about the LIMIT option of FQL. But I need the same functionality like the Graph API that returns <= number of results spcified by the limit parameter but if there are more results there are links to get to these results like

```
"paging": {
 "previous": 
   "https://graph.facebook.com/chickfila/posts?limit=5&since=1298995597",
 "next":
   "https://graph.facebook.com/chickfila/posts?limit=5&until=1293899704"
}
```

Can this be achieved using FQL?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

With the FQL queries, you won't get a "automated" pagination like with the Graph API. The equivalent functionality to since and until can be build by using the relevant time-based fields of the according tables in FQL.

You can have a look here for an introduction:

- https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: So I can use let's say the current time when the request is made and after receiving some results I can get the timestamp of the oldest one and use it to get more results but setting it to a parameter similar to the "until" from that example I posted in my question? Also how am I going to know whether more results are available or  have reached the end?

Comment: Depends on what you actually want to achieve. Can you elaborate a littel bit more?

Comment: I need to get a certain number of photos from the home timeline. When the user reaches the end load some more etc.